# Floyd's triangle variation

Tags: c++

So I have to print Floyd's triangle but like this:

```
7

1

2 3

4 5 6

7 * * *
```

Here is my code, I just can't figure out how to print the `*` at the end  of the last line if there is any space left.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  int n;
  cin>>n;
  int br=1;

  for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {
    for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
      if(br<=n)
        cout<<br<<" ";
      br++;
    }
    if(br<=n)
      cout<<endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: The `n`th row will have `n` items.  Simply subtract the number you have already printed from `n` and then print that many *'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the modified code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  int n, i, j;
  cin>>n;
  int br=1;

  for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
      if(br>n)
        break;
      cout<<br<<" ";
      br++;
    }
    if(br>n)
      break;
    cout<<endl;
  }
  for(int k = j; k <= i; k++)
  {
    cout<<"* ";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that on nth line, there are nth numbers. So, for every line, you must count the numbers you wrote already. So, when you write the number that you need you have written k numbers. Now, you need to add n-k stars.

Comment: i thought about that also but i can't figure out where exactly to position the two new counters so that i don't have a mistake.